# Forward voltage of AlN diode

Tags: led, uv

At 210 nm, the shortest wavelength/highest frequency LED seems to be composed of a Aluminum Nitride junction ([according to this article](http://www.led-professional.com/technology/light-generation/aluminum-nitride-light-emitting-diodes-with-the-shortest-wavelength-towards-dioxin-pcb-decomposition-technology)).

I was wondering, what would the Vf (forward voltage) be of such a diode. I can't seem find any information on deep UV diodes and their respective Vfs (this [source](http://photonsystems.com/downloads/duv_led_datasheet_255nm_LED_performance_information.pdf) claims 7.5V max for a 250nm diode).

Aside from just stating a number (or an approximate number) is there any way (or approximate way) or calculate a diode's Vf vs peak wavelength (perhaps via some form of interpolation of existing diode Vfs)?

Comment: Probably it is not stated anywhere because these diodes are not commercially available. Their power output and efficiency will certainly be extremely small. Anyway, the forward voltage has to be greater than the band gap and this is a material property, but apart from that it is dependent on device characteristics and forward current. Either acquire (i.e., make or have made for you) a diode like this and measure it yourself, or wait until they become commercially available (if ever) and then look at the datasheet.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I get that there is likely no publication regarding forward voltage. I was hoping for an extrapolation based on physics/interpolation based on data. I tried myself to not much avail (based on photon energy). I don't think making an Aluminum Nitride diode is exactly doable at home, just saying...

Comment: Well, if the device characteristics are basically undefined, your only point of reference is the bandgap, as I said in my comment above. This is a lower bound for the forward voltage. For AlN (please correct your question title, by the way) it is a bit more than 6 volts.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I never said they were undefined. The 210 nm diode refers to a specific crafted diode in which there are research papers available for (paid to download however). "A bit more than 6 volts" helps but doesn't explain the reasoning behind the deduction (care to show how that is derived in an answer)? The point is to: a) see if the specific Aluminum Nitride material causes any interesting changes in forward voltage; b) see if such a cutting-edge diode requires something beyond what would normally be needed (due to inefficiencies perhaps).

Comment: In the paper they state that the forward voltage for a 20 mA forward current was 37 V for a MIS-structured diode and 45 V for a PIN-structured one. The hole mobility especially was rather small, although they go into more detail about the electrical characterization in the paper. Since it seems you are asking about this particular diode, does that answer the question?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, if you reference perhaps the link to the paper (or the abstract in which you got it from) and posted it as an answer. I'd like to see how you got the 6V Vf just from the bandgap as well.

Comment: The calculation of the band structure for arbitrary materials from first principles is an involved question that would be more suited to physics.SE than here (and do not expect a full answer even there; better to refer to a text book). But I will certainly give a reference to the paper.

Comment: I *think* you can work out the minimum voltage by converting the the energy of a photon into electron-volts. Like this : [google calculator](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=(planck's+constant)*(speed+of+light)%2F(210+nm)+in+eV) which says 5.9 electron volts. Not too far out. This depends on the carriers having a mass similar to an electron, which might be a very rough assumption. Maybe you should ask the Physics SE.

Comment: @tomnexus this is the same as the band gap energy, for a direct gap device. The device produces the emission wavelength that it does because its band gap is what it is. So this calculation is begging the question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. OK, but I'm suggesting this as a way of estimating diode forward voltage directly from wavelength, not considering the device structure. By assuming carrier mass is the same as an electron, the maximum photon energy in eV is the same as the applied voltage in V. Is this a useful rule of thumb?

Comment: @tomnexus I would say not necessarily, because there are many LEDs with conversion phosphors. If you happen to know that it is a direct gap device and the emission is not converted, then in most cases it should be just as easy to look up the band gap for the material in question. Although we can certainly say that, as long as there are no upconverted LEDs, the photon energy is a very strong lower bound on the forward voltage. But, again, it is a lower bound only, so the usefulness of this in practice can be questioned. 45 V is a lot more than 6 V for the AlN LED, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference for the 210 nm diode is:

> Yoshitaka Taniyasu, Makoto Kasu, and Toshiki Makimoto, "An aluminium
>   nitride light-emitting diode with a wavelength of 210 nanometres",
>   *Nature* **441**, 325 (2006) [doi:10.1038/nature04760]

In this paper, the authors state that they constructed diodes having both a MIS and a PIN structure. The forward voltages for 20 mA forward current were 37 and 45 V, respectively, although the operating current (to produce 0.02 µW of 210 nm emission) was 40 mA, not 20 mA, and they don't directly state the forward voltage for this condition.  The large forward voltages were (seemingly, without having checked it too rigorously) the result of having to drive such a large current through the device given the rather low hole mobility, which was around 30 cm^2 V^-1 s^-1 at room temperature.

The external quantum efficiency was stated to be of the order of 0.000001%.